# Can I avoid to overwrite a column with a NULL value on INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, null, insert

I have two different queries in my php page for the same table, the first one is executed if I have two different values for two columns, but in some case, i can use only the first value, can I do it with the same query or should I use two different queries?

```
// query 1
"INSERT INTO my_table (column_1, column_2) VALUES ('$value_1', '$value_2')";

// second query, used if $value_2 is null
"INSERT INTO my_table (column_1) VALUES ('$value_1')";

// can I do something like this without use a SELECT for column_2 before the INSERT?
$value_2 = null;
"INSERT INTO my_table (column_1, column_2) VALUES ('$value_1', '$value_2')";
// ======================================= new value === ^   |    ^ === mantain old value because it's null
```

so can I execute an INSERT statement with new vals without overwrite the old vals with a null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INSERT` will never overwrite an old record (though it could fail if you try to insert a record that breaks a unique key constraint).  So you can just use the first query, even if `$value_2` is null, and get the same results.

If you want to overwrite records, you will need to use an `UPDATE` statement.  In that case you could overwrite only a single column, if you wanted to.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html for the UPDATE syntax.

There is also `REPLACE` to overwrite old rows in the case of unique keys, but it sounds like this is the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll remember the difference between INSERT and UPDATE, cya